# How to get only year from a date stored in OrientDB

Tags: java, date, orientdb, jbake

I'm working on JBake, and would like to get the year part of the date at which a document was stored.

I know I can get the date by doing

```
SELECT date FROM post
```

And OrientDB will return me a java.util.Date.

I know I can also add the year as another field, but I find this data duplication unsatistfying.

So, is it possible to store the date, and to to have the year extracted through some kind of SQL "function" ?

Typically I would love to do

```
SELECT date, {date.getYear()} FROM post
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the format() function using the [SimpleDateFormat syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
select date.format('YYYY') from post
```